# How to cast to PostgreSQL numeric type?

Tags: java, postgresql, casting, jooq

I need to `trunc()` a `double precision` number that i get from `sum()`. Because `trunc()` only accepts `numeric` i have to cast the `double precision` to `numeric`. In raw SQL this is straight forward:

```
trunc(cast(sum(...) as numeric), 0)
```

I tried the same thing using JOOQ:

```
trunc(sum(...).cast(???), 0)
```

How can i cast to numeric using JOOQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`.cast(SQLDataType.NUMERIC)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html)

---

In jOOQ version 3.11 onwards the use of `PostgresDataType.NUMERIC` has been deprecated, but this is an alternative approach for older versions: 
[`.cast(PostgresDataType.NUMERIC)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDataType.html)